# Cannot debug some of the code in process w3wp.exe (Debugger is not registered)

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, w3wp

Attempting to debug a VB.NET Visual Web Part I am receiving the following error message.

[image]

This error happens straight after I press play and and prior to any of the code in my webpart actually executing. I have tried googling and just thinking through what this error might be referring to but can't come up with anything.

Comment: And you configured debugging in web.config how?

Answer (score 0):

I never start debug in SP project not like in a Web one.

1. Rebuild your webpart project, check that you are configurates as
   'Debug'.
2. Add your process (w3wp.exe) to debug (Ctrl+Alt+P). Or add to your
   code where you would like to debug (I think this is same in VB
           also):

   ```
           System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
   ```